# Is there any way to decide what to be print when we enter a list variable in R?

Tags: r

We define a function which returns a list. We assing the returned list to a variable. When we enter it to the console, it prints whole list. Is there anyway to prefer what to be print from that list.

For example, I want it to print out only "tm$note" when I enter "tm".. instead of printing whole list which fills out the console :/

```
> summary(tm)
         Length Class  Mode     
aucM      6     -none- numeric  
prbM      6     -none- numeric  
mapM      6     -none- numeric  
perfAll  18     -none- numeric  
msdM     18     -none- numeric  
predlab   2     -none- list     
note      1     -none- character
settings  1     -none- character
> tm$note
[1] "this is an example of...bla bla.. "
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the class of your list and define a `summary` method:

```
tm <- list(note="this is the note", junk="other junk", numericJunk=1:5)
class(tm) <- "myClass"
summary.myClass <- function(object, ...) {
     object$note
}
summary(tm)
## [1] "this is the note"
```

For more control you could define `print` methods for `myClass` objects, or have `summary.myClass` return an object of class "summary.myClass" and define a `print.summary.myClass` method (see e.g. `stats:::print.summary.lm`).

Rereading your question slightly more carefully: defining `print.myClass` might be what you want:

```
 print.myClass <- function(object,...) {
     print(object$note)
 }
 tm
 ## [1] "this is the note"
```

(you could also use `cat()` instead of `print()`).

If you want you could define the above as `summary.list` or `print.list` instead, so that *all* lists would be printed in this way, but that seems dangerous/overly general to me ... it's definitely better practice to specify that your value is a special *kind* of list (i.e. assign it a class).

Comment: well, if it's not what you want, feel free to edit your question to make it clearer ...

Comment: I dont know how can I make it clearer.. I dont want get that result when I enter summary(tm), I want to get it when I enter only tm.. Anyway..

Comment: @BenBolker - I like your answer, but I think I know what is being asked here. When you return the name of e.g. a fitted `lm` model, you only see the formula and coefficients. How is that done without printing all of the information contained within?

Comment: OK, I think you want to define the `print` method.  See edited answer.